# Live desktop feed on green screen: thesis presentation

Tags: mac, greenscreen, presentation

Next week I'm doing my final presentation on my thesis about Android development. Because I go to school in the Netherlands, and my internship is in New York City, I'm going to do my presentation through the likes of something like Skype or Google Hangouts.

For this presentation I was hoping I could use a green screen and project my presentation on the background, like [this presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sONcojECWXs) by Reto Meier on Android 4.4. The difference here is that I think the video has been edited in after the video recording, and I would like to be able to control my presentation live.

Would anyone know of a way to accomplish this? In short, I'm looking for software that can display what's happening on my Mac monitor on a green screen background. I would then like to be able to use that combined view of me and the presentation as a background as a webcam view for Hangouts or Skype.

Thanks in advance,
Dennis Altena

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Mac, download "Cam Twist." It offers reasonable live keying, and it can even put you as picture in picture.

If you use the right browser, I.e. Firefox with the Google Hangouts plugin necessary for hangouts, "Camtwist" will just be an option in the list of cameras.

Download it [here.](http://camtwiststudio.com/)

Comment: Thank you for the solution. The application seems to be working, but I can't seem to get an HD signal through to the other end. The internet speed should easily be fast enough, and my view is displayed as 720p on my screen, but I can't get a clear image on the other end. Would you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: You may need to force your resolution. If you haven't already, go to preferences and look for the "force resolresolution" option. There may or may not be an actual button for it to be streamed HD. I don't know other than that.